# Patching \captionof fails

Tags: captions, patching

I would like to execute this or that command depending on whether `\captionof` is used for a `figure` or a `table`.

So I patch `\captionof` with `etoolbox` to see if the `float type` parameter is of type `table` or `figure` using a string comparison. However, for some reason I don't understand, my changes have no effect.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,etoolbox}
\newif\iffigure
\newif\iftable

\AtBeginDocument{
    \pretocmd{\captionof}{%
        \ifstrequal{#2}{table}{%
            \global\tabletrue%
            %... execute some code
        }
        {}%
        \ifstrequal{#2}{figure}{%
            \global\figuretrue%
            %... execute some code
        }
        {}%
    }
    {}
    {}
}

\begin{document}
{\captionof{figure}{A caption.}}

\iffigure Yes \else No \fi
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should probably try `\typeout{\meaning\caption of} ` to see what that macro is made of. It probably calls some internal macro that you need to patch instead (not at pc so cannot test)

Comment: \captionof has no arguments. It only checks the next token and then calls an internal command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As daleif mentioned in comment, the macro that actually deals with the `\captionof` arguments isn't `\captionof` itself, but `\caption@of`; there is some pre-work done to check for the possibility of needing a unnumbered (starred) caption. So, you need to patch `\caption@of`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption,etoolbox}
\newif\iffigure

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\caption@of}{%
  \ifstrequal{#2}{table}{%
    \global\tabletrue%
    %... execute some code
  }
  {}%
  \ifstrequal{#2}{figure}{%
    \global\figuretrue%
    %... execute some code
  }
  {}%
}
{}% Success
{}% Failure
\makeatother

\begin{document}

{\captionof{figure}{A caption.}}

\iffigure Yes \else No \fi

\end{document}
```

Another approach would be to capture the arguments as part of `\captionof` through a redefinition:

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\oldcaptionof\captionof% Store \captionof in \oldcaptionof
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\captionof}{s m m}{% Redefine \captionof
    \ifstrequal{#2}{table}{%
      \global\tabletrue%
      %... execute some code
    }
    {}%
    \ifstrequal{#2}{figure}{%
      \global\figuretrue%
      %... execute some code
    }
    {}%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}% Check if star was used
      {\oldcaptionof*{#2}{#3}}% Starred \captionof
      {\oldcaptionof {#2}{#3}}% Unstarred \captionof
  }%
}
```

Comment: The first approach doesn't work at all.